# Is it possible that the pre-processor can change the sign for operator overloading function?

Tags: c++, generics, operator-overloading

I want to write just one operator overloading function but it can perform ==,!=,<=,<,> or >=.
Is it possible that we can use preprocessor to change the sign of the function? something like this

```
class A{
    private:
         int b;
         //some code
    public:
         #define macro(sign) sign
         bool operator macro(sign)(const A& obj){
              return (b macro(sign) obj.b)
         }  
}
```

Sorry, I know it is quite impossible to do something like this.But I am just curious whether I can write a generic operator overloading function.

Comment: Don't *ever* use macros unless it's the only possible option (which is *rare*).

Comment: You had me at "Don't _ever_ use macros...".

Answer (score 2):

C++20 has the spaceship operator that will give you all of this for free for this class:

```
auto operator<=>(const A& obj) const = default;
```

If your class is more complex such that a memberwise comparison does not suffice, you'll need to define both `operator<=>` (returning [one of the `_ordering` types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/compare)) and `operator==` because using `<=>` for non-default equality can easily fall into a performance trap for any type containing something like a string or vector. The other comparisons will be rewritten to use these two operators.

Here's a [full example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/LTXdAD):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <compare>

struct A {
    int b;

    auto operator<=>(const A&) const = default;
};

struct B {
    int b;

    // This could return auto but this is an example.
    std::strong_ordering operator<=>(const B& other) const {
        return other.b <=> b;
    }

    bool operator==(const B& other) const {
        return b == other.b;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a1{1}, a2{2};

    assert(a1 < a2);
    assert(a2 >= a1);
    assert(a1 != a2);

    B b1{1}, b2{2};

    assert(b2 < b1);
    assert(b1 >= b2);
    assert(b1 != b2);
}
```

Comment: Quick note, as of llvm 10, the flag for C++20 is now c++20 instead of c++2a. You will get different results (not for this code), at least I did when playing with concepts.

Comment: @sweenish, Interesting that it's not an alias flag then, but thanks, I've been meaning to update the hotstring I use to generate those options.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you've noticed the logic of all of them will be very similar--good eye!

It's actually common to only write one operator, and it's usually the `operator<`. We can then use that everywhere else. So your implementation may look like:

```
class A {
    bool operator<(const A& rhs) const {
        // Custom comparison logic here...
    }

    bool operator>(const A& rhs) const { return rhs < *this; }
    bool operator<=(const A& rhs) const { return !(rhs < *this); }
    bool operator>=(const A& rhs) const { return !(*this < rhs); }
    bool operator==(const A& rhs) const { return !(*this < rhs) && !(rhs < *this); }
    bool operator!=(const A& rhs) const { return (*this < rhs) || (rhs < *this); }
};
```